# Android TextView in ScrollView not working- Force Close

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, forceclose

Im trying to create a textview that is able to scroll a large amount of text. I nested it inside of a scrollview and I get force closes on my phone and tablet when attempting to test it. When I run without the scrollview, it works, but does not scroll, obviously. Here is what I have in my XML file for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:isScrollContainer="true">    
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/tutView">

   </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT: LogCat info:

```
02-10 14:51:44.402: W/dalvikvm(5948): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3c1f8)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rg.ah/rg.ah.TutViewerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3188)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:260)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1855)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at rg.ah.TutViewerActivity.onCreate(TutViewerActivity.java:25)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-10 14:51:44.414: E/AndroidRuntime(5948):     ... 11 more
02-10 14:51:44.496: D/dalvikvm(5948): GC_CONCURRENT freed 192K, 4% free 9285K/9607K, paused 2ms+9ms
```

EDIT 2: Added my onCreate for the error in question. This takes the item that was touched in a list on the main view and displays this with more information in a textview.

```
public class TutViewerActivity  extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.textview);

    Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();
    String content = launchingIntent.getData().toString();

    TextView viewer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutView);
    viewer.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    viewer.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

    setContentView(viewer);
}
}
```

Comment: A multi-line `TextView` will scroll if it contains more text than it can display.

Comment: What does the LogCat say when it Force Closes?

Comment: You know ... Force close means error .. So where is a logcat output?

Comment: Added the LogCat for you all.

Comment: I have also tried using the `android:inputType` with the Multiline inpute type and does not scroll, just darkens the screen a bit when trying to scroll...

Answer (score 1):

The exception is telling you `IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`.

This means that you try to put a view which already have a parent inside another view.

make sure you don't `setContentView(R.id.tutView)` or something like that.

If the name of your layout xml is `main.xml`, the right thing to do would be `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.

**EDIT**

Why did you write this line ? `setContentView(viewer);` this is what's wrong.

You've already set it's parent as content view, remove it and you're fine.

Comment: @Rekar Yeah the error is in the onCreate not the XML. It even tell's you `at rg.ah.TutViewerActivity.onCreate(TutViewerActivity.java:25` so line 25. I'm with Rotemmiz it's prob your setContentView()

Comment: Sry it took me so long. I added the code in question unedited for you to look at. What I did was instead of putting the textview into a scrollview, I kept it at top level and added the `setMovementMethod` code to allow the text to scroll as a temporary fix. Im still very much interested in fixing my previous code.